# angular4 *ngFor multiple filters not working

Tags: angular, typescript

**html file**

```
 [(ngModel)]="termCategory" (click)="fillterCategory($event)" 

 ngDefaultControl>{{cat.nameCategory}}</button></li>

 <div class="product col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let item of dat  | 

 filter:term | filter:termCategory">
```

**ts file**

```
 fillterCategory(category){

    this.termCategory=category.target.textContent;

   console.log(this.termCategory);

  }
```

**pipe file**

```
 transform(dat: any, termCategory: any): any {
   if(termCategory===undefined  ) return dat;

    return  dat.filter((product)=>{

 return product.categoryId.toLowerCase().includes(termCategory.toLowerCase())

      })

 }
```

I am trying to apply 2 filters on a div.
one by a text input(it is working fine)
second by button click.. I do not get any errors but the filter's are not working .
how do I apply 2 filters on a single div with *ngFor?

Comment: What is being logged in your .ts file? Is `termCategory` what your expecting? Does it contain any extra whitespace or anything else that may affect the filtering?

Comment: with the input i am filltering by name.. and with the button i want to filler by category. i get no result

Comment: You put a return, that it no corresponde :dat.filter((product=> {product.cataegodyId.toLowerCase().includes(termCategory.toLowerCase())

Comment: can u please explane ?